# 3d reconstruction - projective to metric or quasi-affine to metric upgrade

Tags: computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

I'm currently experimenting with auto-calibration and have achieved a quasi-affine reconstruction but am unsure how to proceed.
Could anyone please refer me to a good resource for upgrades to metric reconstruction. I've had a look at a few (e.g. Pollefeys or Gherardis approach), but I wasn't able to find out what is actually the recommended way to go in this area.

I would really appreciate your insights. Thank you!

Note: I'm just using a stereo pair for reconstruction.